# Clear input border, back to default

Tags: css

So someone has applied the following style:

```
select, input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}
```

Why they've done it this way I will never know. But now I have a requirement to remove the border above, i.e. go back to the standard browser specific textbox borders but only in a few places. *I know, I know, it'll look weird* but I'm doing what I'm told.

What CSS will **revert** the border set above?

I've tried

```
border:;
border:auto;
```

Neither work!

Just to clarify, **I can't just remove the css style**. I need to override it, if possible!

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199141/overriding-css-properties-that-dont-have-default-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you can't just delete the line of code like user2063626 suggests?

If not just do this:

```
select, input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Edit:

Add a `:not` to your css selector so it doesn't select the input you want to be left alone.

```
select:not(#yourinput), input[type="text"]:not(#yourinput), input[type="password"]:not(#yourinput) {
    border: 1px solid #999999 !important;
}
```

Edit2:

You're best option is to either add a class, or use a more specific selector (`#div select` instead of just `select`). That way the css only targets the ones you want it to, and not affecting any new ones you may add.

Or, if it would be easier, just add a class, or use a more specific selector on the `select` that you don't want to have the styles, then apply the default styles to it.

You can find the default styles at [mozilla.org](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/layout/style/forms.css?force=1) just search for `select`.

Comment: No, thats not right, that'll give me no border. I want the **default** border. I can't becuase it's used in other places in the form and all over the site. I just wnat to override it in one place in one form

Comment: You could add a not selector so it doesn't include the border on the input you want to be set to default.

Comment: Beautiful, everyday's a school day not seen a :not before!

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful to you http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Just found out this is CSS3, which is a pain as I need to support IE7+ (oh well good idea just not going to work): http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below class to your css and put to input which you dont want have border.

```
input.noBorder{
      border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't do this becuase it's used in other places in the form and all over the site. I just wnat to override it in one place in one form